# How to remove duplicate unordered elements from list of lists?

Tags: python, list, lambda

I have a list of lists:

```
[[1, 2, 5], [1, 7], [1, 6, 1], [2, 6], [2, 1, 5], [7, 1]]
```

I'm trying to remove elements `[2,1,5]` & `[7,1]` from it since elements `[1,2,5]` & `[1,7]` have the same elements and the order doesn't matter.

What is the fastest way to remove such elements?

Comment: You might want to use sets.

Answer (score 4):

You can keep track of the already seen elements in a `set`. You can sort them before, in order to "normalize" them and thus ignore the order of the elements.

```
>>> lst = [[1, 2, 5], [1, 7], [1, 6, 1], [2, 6], [2, 1, 5], [7, 1]]
>>> seen = set()
>>> unique = []
>>> for x in lst:
...     srtd = tuple(sorted(x))
...     if srtd not in seen:
...         unique.append(x)
...         seen.add(srtd)
...         
>>> unique
[[1, 2, 5], [1, 7], [1, 6, 1], [2, 6]]
```

You have to convert the sorted elements to tuples before putting them into the set, as lists are not hashable, though. You might also consider using `frozenset` instead, but that will not work well with entries that have duplicate elements, such as `[1, 6, 1]`

Answer (score 2):

You can create a list of sets as follows:

```
my_list = [[1, 2, 5], [1, 7], [1, 6, 1], [2, 6], [2, 1, 5], [7, 1]]
new_list = [frozenset(element) for element in my_list]
```

In order to remove the duplicates, do:

```
cleaned_set = set(new_list)
```

cleaned_set is a collection of sets, therefore contains no duplicates.

Comment: This turns `[1,6,1]` into `{1,6}`

Comment: Yes, this only works for the case where duplicates concern only the elements of the lists without taking into account the 'cardinality'.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
a = [[1, 2, 5], [1, 7], [1, 6, 1], [2, 6], [2, 1, 5], [7, 1]]
b = []
for k in a:
    if not sorted(k) in b:
        b.append(k)

>>> b
[[1, 2, 5], [1, 7], [1, 6, 1], [2, 6]]
```

**Ps:** if you have duplicates in your input list, think of using `set()` to remove them before using the loop.

**Edit:**

If the order doesn't matter:

```
a = [[1, 2, 5], [1, 7], [1, 6, 1], [2, 6], [2, 1, 5], [7, 1]]
b = [[1, 2, 5], [7, 1], [1, 6, 1], [2, 6], [2, 1, 5], [1, 7]]

>>> list(map(list, set(tuple(sorted(k)) for k in a)))
[[2, 6], [1, 1, 6], [1, 2, 5], [1, 7]]

>>> list(map(list, set(tuple(sorted(k)) for k in b)))
[[2, 6], [1, 1, 6], [1, 2, 5], [1, 7]]
```

Comment: But what if `[7, 1]` comes before `[1, 7]`?

Comment: @MarkRansom In this case my code will not work as expected. I need to change my approach in this case.